FireDAC Firebird Connection rejected by remote interface
I use Delphi 10.4.2. I downloaded the examples.fdb ( 3.0 ) directly for Firebird.org.


When I click on Test I instantly get a [FireDAC][Phys][FB]connection rejected by remote interface.
I am stuck. The Delphi website says you are probably connecting to FB Server with FB Driver using GDS32.DLL.

Which version of fbclient.dll or gds32.dll are you using? This error can happen if you use fbclient.dll of Firebird 2.5 and older, and you haven't changed the configuration of Firebird 3 to allow unencrypted connections and the legacy authentication (though the better fix is to use the Firebird 3 or higher fbclient.dll).

Also, why did you install a client-only install: you also need Firebird server to connect.

@MarkRotteveel : I will try to make a full install . Even if I just want to open a copied over FDB file I need to have a fully installed Firebird Server ?

@MarkRotteveel : I've installed Firebird 3 Latest from website, I have the demo database . Now I did a full install it does not help. Still the same error. I am using the DLL from the Firebird 3 Installation directory .

Once you have a Firebird server running, it will use some port to listen to incoming connections. Use this port number in your connection parameters.

Also server process should have access to DB file.

Firebird is client-server DBMS. Yes, you have to have server to work with databases. In this regard Firebird is not different from Oracle, for example.

What is the configuration of AuthServer, AuthClient, UserManager and WireCrypt in your firebird.conf? Can you connect with ISQL to a database (with SYSDBA), if so, what is the output of select SEC$PLUGIN from SEC$USERS where SEC$USER_NAME = 'SYSDBA';

I needed to download the Firebird 2.5 Embedded driver. After this in Delphi I configured FDConnection as above. I also dropped an FDPhysFBDriverLink1 on the form. Here I checked Embedded and set the Vendorlib to the fbembeded.dll. And it works.
